# Protection of my loads (batteries + equipment) from alternator

Tags: batteries, protection, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, alternator

I have an aftermarket additional alternator (24v, 100A) installed in vehicle without external regulator (don't know about internal regulator). I have found this alternator locally probably used alternator dismantle from used vehicle. Normally its voltage cutoff at 28.5 voltage, but we have observed that some of these alternators go up to 32v.

Our installation is like this

Alternator->battery + equipment. Alternator will give current to both simultaneously i-e batteries and equipment (according to their needs). I need protection for my equipment and batteries from alternator by overvoltage and over current which may heat up the alternator if max current is drawn by it from load.

How can I protect my loads (batteries + equipment)? If alternator get faulty and gives overvoltage or load draws max current? any controlling device which can fulfill my requirement?